# .htaccess com URL amigavel que permite uso do método GET

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Olá, meu sistema faz uso de URL amigável, porem a autenticação da API do MercadoLivre retorna ao meu sistema usando `?code=XXXX`, oque eu preciso é que o site funcione de forma híbrida, tanto com a URL amigável quanto usando o `$_GET`, parecido com a seguinte URL: `site.com/dashboard/principal?code=XXXXXXXX`
Não tenho praticamente nenhum conhecimento na configuração desse .htaccess então se alguém puder me dar uma luz eu agradeço.

Esse aqui é o meu `.htaccess` atual:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dados=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

dando uma boa olhada na Internet encontrei uma solução para meu problema e estou compartilhando com vocês:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dados=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Comment: se puder, marque sua resposta como aceita pra deixar a postagem mais completa (clicando no V verdinho do lado da resposta)